# Thread keeps hanging on Socket / Printwriter interaction

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter

My program runs for a while (about 20 seconds) after that it sends fewer and fewer messages until it stops. I've made a Thread dump and it points me to the following line of code where the thread stops:

```
if(s.isClosed() || !s.isConnected() || s.isInputShutdown() || s.isOutputShutdown() || out == null || out.checkError()) {
```

This is a part of my thread dump

```
    "class xxx.xxx.xxx" prio=10 tid=0x000000000200d800 nid=0x6e7f waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f63172b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.flush(PrintWriter.java:291)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000000ec810218> (a java.io.BufferedWriter)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.checkError(PrintWriter.java:330)
```

This thread dump info points out that the problem lies in Printwriter.checkError(). But i can't understand why it would stop here.

Below is the code in it's context. (receivers is a `Map<Socket, PrintWriter>`)

```
public void parseMessage(final byte[] bytes) {
    synchronized (receivers) {
        for (final Socket s : receivers.keySet()) {
            final PrintWriter out = receivers.get(s);
            if(s.isClosed() || !s.isConnected() || s.isInputShutdown() || s.isOutputShutdown() || out == null || out.checkError()) {
                receivers.remove(s);
                failedToConnect(s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), s.getPort());
                continue;
            }
            queue.add(out, bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 14 januari (10:00 GMT+1):**

Replaced the `PrintWriter` with a `BufferedWriter`

**Update 14 januari (16:00 GMT+1):**

I've runned some more tests and it turned out that some kind of communication problems between some network/readers is causing troubles. The application is sending data to some readers in it's internal network en to some readers in some outside networks (through internet). What exactly causes this is still unknown a this point but there are some clues. After a few restarts i could see that connections between two networks where not closed so the connections stayed open. I still don't know what is exactly happening here but it looks to me it's some kind of network issue. On de server side the connections stays in "FIN_WAIT1" and on the reader side it stays "ESTABLISHED". It looks like the reader won't signal to close the connection even a signal has been send to close it.

Comment: Side comment: `for (final Map.Entry<Socket, PrintWriter> e : receivers.entrySet()) { final PrintWriter out = e.getValue(); final Socket s = e.getKey();` would be a little more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s.isClosed() || !s.isConnected() || s.isInputShutdown() || s.isOutputShutdown() || out == null || out.checkError())
```

This is a series of mostly futile tests.

- if the socket is closed you shouldn't be in this part of the code at all.
- if the socket isn't connected, ditto.
- if you have shutdown the socket for input it doesn't mean you can't write.
- if you have shutdown the socket for output you shouldn't be in this part of the code.
- if `out` is null you shouldn't be in this part of the code.
- Testing `checkError()` is good, but you shouldn't really be using `PrintWriter` over a network at all, because it swallows exceptions. It would be better to use `BufferedWriter` and let the exceptions tell you about things going wrong as they happen, rather than on the next write as you are doing here.

You also need to understand that `Socket.isClosed()` only tells you whether *you* have closed the `Socket.` Similarly, `Socket.isConnected()` only tells you that you have connected the `Socket,` or received it already connected via a constructor, or `ServerSocket.accept()`. Same goes for `isInputShutdown()` and `isOutputShutdown().` They only tell you what you have done to the `Socket.` None of these methods tells you anything about the state of the *connection*.

> This thread dump info points out that the problem lies in Printwriter.checkError(). But i can't understand why it would stop here.

Because, as the stack trace also tells you, it is calling `flush().` If that blocks it means you have overrun the reader, and TCP is waiting for him to read some data to free buffer space in his socket receive buffer and therefore your socket send buffer. Until that happens, the underlying `send()` will block. Nothing you can do about that, except speed up the reader.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I'm going to replace the `Printwriter` and remove those socket checks and just catch the exceptions when writing to the `BufferedWriter`. My reader is fast enough though. I'm not even writing 1% of what the reader could handle. This afternoon i'm going to run more tests on our servers and hopefully i will find something that is blocking the flush method. Maybe a failing switch/network card or something like that, that's causing the flush to block.

Comment: @Kevin The evidence is against you. A failing network element would ultimately cause an IOException, not a block long enough for you to get thread dumps from and ask questions about.

Answer (score 0):

when a thread is blocked its most likely it's waiting on I/O request
take a look at this link it's very similar to what you are experiencing 
[how-to-analyze-java-thread-dumps](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-analyze-java-thread-dumps/)

Comment: I agree, but what could cause the printwriter not to flush its content when checkError is called. De client that the data is written to is fully reachable. Should i be looking into operating system issues or network issues in switches or something like that?